# Android heterogeneous gridview like pinterest?

Tags: java, android, pinterest

Is it possible to create pinterest like layout on Android using `GridView`? I want to create image gallery using `GridView` but I am not sure if it is good solution. I do not want create three `LinearLayouts` (I think that this solution is not good: [Pinterest style listview or gridview in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9897808/pinterest-style-listview-or-gridview-in-android))

Any ideas ;)?

[image]

Comment: nut sure if that's a gridview on the picture.

Comment: GridView will not work here because `height` is not same for all images

Comment: It really looks just like three columns of imageViews to me.

Comment: 3 ListViews might be better because you can get some recycling going. However, it may also cause unwanted UI behaviour given that you can scroll each column independently.

Comment: I think the best approach would be to create your own view and handle the draw code yourself.

Comment: @CheJami: probably it is the only solution ;/

Comment: @radzio: did you find out the solution?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Create layout like as follow

```
<ScrollView...>
<LinearLayout....
   android:id="@+id/linear1"
   orientation="horizontal">

   <LinearLayout....
     android:id="@+id/linear2"
     android:layout_weight="0.33"
     orientation="vertical">

   <LinearLayout....
     android:id="@+id/linear3"
     android:layout_weight="0.33"
     orientation="vertical">

   <LinearLayout....
     android:layout_weight="0.33"
     orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Now add your `ImageView` dynamically in layouts

```
linear1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear1);
linear2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear2);
linear3 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear3);

for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
   ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
   iv.setImageResource(R.id.icon);

   int j = count % 3;  <---- 
   if(j==0)
       linear1.addView(iv);
   else if(j==1)
       linear2.addView(iv);
   else
       linear3.addView(iv); 
}
```

**output:**

[image]

Comment: I know that it is possible but I don't want to use LinearyLayout because of bad view recycling. This solution will not work well with many imageviews.

Comment: ok as u wish but i have done this and i am loading 120 images from URL

Comment: This is a very neat solution.

Comment: Hm... I will check this solution after work. Maybe it's what I need ;-)

Comment: @downvoter: plz care to say reason for downvote

Comment: is it run fast without problems with memory consumption?

Comment: @MAC pleas help me for same issue

Comment: @chintankhetiya: whats problem ?

Comment: @downvoter care to say reason for downvote

Comment: @MAC How can I check which ImageView was clicked with this code? I want to be able to differentiate exactly which one was clicked and move to a different Activity (like a position variable would give me in an onItemClickListener)

Comment: @Kgrover: use `iv.setTag(""+i)` and set `onClick()` and use `v.getTag()`

Comment: this solution would work, but if there are a lot of items it could cause both slowliness of initializations and OOM . i've added a possible solution that uses the same idea of an adapterView.

Comment: Best library https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridViewDemo

Answer (score 25):

I've been playing with this also (used LinearLayout) but at the end I had lot of problems with memory consumption (especially when I had to reload the items). I settled on simple solution which 
uses two synchronized **ListViews**. This way I can exploit internal **caching** which helps a lot.
To do this I had to use **OnTouchListener** and **OnScrollListener** who synchronize lists.
Here's an example:

https://github.com/vladexologija/PinterestListView

[image]

Comment: can you post the sample code for this?

Comment: What exactly do you need? Whole Activity source?

Comment: well anything more than the above code actually. Being a novice android developer, it's going to take me a while to grasp the concepts that you laid out.

Comment: There you go. There are still a lot of things to do (fix few bugs, optimize, simplify...) but this version works fine. What's most important it uses recycling!

Comment: @vladexologija Thank you so much for such a great post.

Comment: @vladexologija I want to set the images from my SDCard. As you have used Integer array, I am not able to pass the path to the images. Any idea on how to achieve this ?? It would be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What this example does is that it just syncs two lists. If you build any two lists with their custom adapters (in your case loading image with some lazy loading) they should work with minor changes to posted code.

Comment: does anyone know how to handle onItemClick, it doesn't work for me

Answer (score 21):

Some useful libraries for implementing Pinterest-like grid view:

- https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridViewDemo
- https://github.com/jacobmoncur/QuiltViewLibrary
- https://github.com/huewu/PinterestLikeAdapterView
- https://github.com/vladexologija/PinterestListView
- https://github.com/expilu/AntipodalWall

Comment: Is there an example with horizontal scroll?

Comment: used the staggeredGridView library in my app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.taureano.amazicons . Worked great so up voting this answer. There is a small bug in orientation change in the library but i found the fix in stack overflow.

Answer (score 7):

For Recent visitors to this question , I would suggest using `RecyclerView`
with `StaggedGridLayoutManager`. It's having more than enough functions and flexibility.

Answer (score 6):

A standalone helper for synchronizing scrolling of 2 ListViews: https://gist.github.com/yanchenko/6179793

Answer (score 3):

I am using this lib: https://github.com/huewu/PinterestLikeAdapterView.

It works pretty well. The only issue I have is that the `setOnItemClickListener` and `setOnItemLongClickListener` are a bit buggy so I set the listeners directly on the convertView.

Answer (score 2):

This library comes from the Etsy application:
https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid