# Android is there ClickListener for linearLayout using addView?

Tags: android, listview, android-linearlayout, pinterest

I'm trying to create pinterest like layout. I find a way to achieve this: [Android heterogeneous gridview like pinterest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736658/android-heterogeneous-gridview-like-pinterest/)!

However the problem is: I want to view item details after clicking each picture. But as I am using LinearLayout.addView() to add all the ImageViews, I'm not sure how I can get it clickable?

Is there anyway to be able to click each item on the view?

Comment: thanks everyone! It works. I forgot to set clickable on my self-defined view.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this pretty easily by adding tag information to your image view that can be displayed when clicked.

Adding your image view would look like:

```
ImageView iv = new ImageView(context);
iv.setOnClickListener(your_listener);
iv.setTag("Item information");
linearLayout.addView(iv);
```

Then in your click listener:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v instanceof ImageView) {
        String info = (String)v.getTag();
        /* Show information here */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // ADD your action here

            }
        });
```

or make your class implement the `OnClickListner` Interface and override the `onClick()` method

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //do magic
        }
    });
```

And in your layout file mark the ImageView as clickable:

```
<ImageView
...
android:clickable="true">
...
</ImageView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on the code that you linked, you can add a listener to each image view as you create it:

```
linear1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear1);
linear2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear2);
linear3 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear3);

for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
   ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
   iv.setImageResource(R.id.icon);
   iv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View v) {
           //Your click code
       }
   }

   int j = count % 3;  <---- 
   if(j==0)
       linear1.addView(iv);
   else if(j==1)
       linear2.addView(iv);
   else
       linear3.addView(iv); 
}
```