# Extending AbsListView example

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I would like to build a custom List (Pinterest grid layout) and I would like to extend `AbsListView`. Are there good examples around? It seems very very difficult.

Thanks
Tobia

Comment: I am not sure if it can be done with a `ListView` (most answers on SO suggest that actually. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11736658/450534). But this just might be helpful to you: https://github.com/expilu/AntipodalWall. Again, it has absolutely nothing to do with a `ListView`.

Comment: AntipodalWall is a ViewGroup like putting different LinearLayout...bad performance for what we need to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

i've created a [**nice post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18557720/gridview-with-different-cells-sizes-pinterest-style) about this and found out [**this is the best one**](https://github.com/huewu/PinterestLikeAdapterView).

however, do note that just like the other libraries, it has its own issues. what i've found is that when you call notifyDatasetChanged() on it, you get weird pairs of views and positions on the getView method (link [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19243670/how-to-avoid-refreshing-of-cells-on-when-calling-notifydatasetchanged-for-pint) about this issue). also i've found out that it doesn't call the "onScrollChanged" method at all (link [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19134712/onscrollchanged-doesnt-get-called-for-pinterest-listview) about this issue)

even though this library is nice, i would also like to see a tutorial on extending the abdListView.