# How to Use Adapter While Filling Layouts

Tags: android, android-layout

I know it may be **weird** that I want to succeed.

Let me explain whole in details. Firstly, I want to use two ListView looking in an Activity screen. Just like how **Pinterest** looks like. (I'm not sure is it true but it's named as **heterogeneous gridview**.) There is also one thing that I needed to implement: **lazy loading**. There are about **30 images** in my activity, so that's not good to fetch all images at one time. That's why I needed lazy load.

So in first, I pondered on that I how obtain that appearance, I mean heterogeneous gridview. Then decided to add to `LinearLayout` in a `ScrollView`. Linears have **vertical** orientation. With thay approach, I added my new views by using odd-even method in Linear Layouts.

Althought, there weren't any adapter so according to my knowledge, there is no way to controll which items would be displayed. So lazy load is not suitable.

I've also tried two `ListView` in an `Activity`, but got some lag and also synchronous scroll problems. On the other hand it has a bad recycling.

So in this scenario, I want to ask is there way to fill LinearLayouts using `Adapter`? Or what would you recommend to create a heterogeneous gridview but also with lazy load.

If my approaches are wrong, I would not hasitate to change it.

Any clue would be great for me. If there is something unclear, please specify it. I'll explain with more details.

Comment: First link on google search : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736658/android-heterogeneous-gridview-like-pinterest

Comment: Thanks, checked all answers already, PinterestListView is suitable for lazy load but not has synchronous scroll, lag problem. StaggeredGridView and AntipodalWall is not suitable for lazy load, btw that libraries is not up-to-date. So I need my own library.

Comment: For loading images lazily you can use [LazyList](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList) library. I haven't used the PinterestListView, but I think you can implement a asymmetric grids by following the logic in that library.

Comment: You may also want to check the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14457328/1186983

Comment: Thank you for answers, I'll check and tell the result.

Comment: @Supreethks, LazyList is fine in the terms of lazy loading but not enough efficent for heterogeneous gridview. That library is based on ListView&Adapter, so if I want to use it with heterogeneous gridview, there should be synchronous scrolling. That's already what I'm asking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a lot of research, finally I found a library which have **lazy loading** and **heterogeneous gridview** and also not has any scroll or recycling lags/problems.

Maurycy's **StaggeredGridView** is completely what I'm looking for.

Here is the [library](https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridView) and also there is a [demo](https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridViewDemo) too.

Answer (score 1):

If I get your question right, here is what you need: http://spinlist.autsia.com/

Comment: Dmytro, thanks. As I answered to Supreethks's comment, I needed lazy load with heterogeneous gridview. So that also would not fit on my problem.