# I need a GridView that has 2 columns and rows should be expand depends on the number of items to be inflate

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

GridView must expand depending upon number of items to be inflate.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, could you please re-tag the question to indicate the language/framework you are using?

Comment: php? asp.net? windows forms? iPhone? Android?

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14441394/custom-grid-view-with-row-span-and-column-span) might help .