# Gridview like pinterest in horizontal scroll view

Tags: android, gridview

I saw this [libs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18869619/1081896), but I want to get horizontal scroll view. How can i do this or someone know more usefull solution or github project?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is an android widget called HorizontalScrollView you can find it here 
[Android HorizontalScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html)

and there is an example on how to use it here 
[Example on HorizontalScrollView](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/horizontalscrollview/android-horizontalscrollview-example/)

Take a look on this library

https://github.com/oasis2008/PinterestListView