# Vertical Grid view in android

Tags: android, gridview, android-recyclerview

[image]

I need to make this **UI** in android and I know that I can do it with the help of `GridView` but what I cannot understand is that how to set the margin for the `TextView`.
Can anyone help me with this?
Or any other suggestion except `GridView`. I was even thinking of `RecyclerView`.

Comment: I think it's not easy to do above layout with `RecyclerView`

Comment: and what about gridview

Comment: Even `GridView`  will not help you in this case, You need custom view or library for this

Comment: can you suggest me any library?

Comment: try using lookup span do some tweeks , take reference from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736658/android-heterogeneous-gridview-like-pinterest

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: welcome also have look on answer's library, if `RecyclerView` not help you then you will get idea how to design the custom view

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this](https://proandroiddev.com/how-to-create-a-bubble-selection-animation-on-android-627044da4854) library could be interesting for you.